# Connecting to a local SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

While making `web.config`, I tried to connect local SQL Server database with the web

```
<add key="DSN" value="server=localhost;uid=test_demo;pwd=1234;database=DB_PRE"/>
```

However using "DSN" with value server = localhost does not successfully connected to the local SQL Server database. And I'm not sure with creating `uid` and `pwd` I want to know how to use "DSN" to connect to the local.

I'm using SQL Server 2008, IIS Express 7.

Comment: Try adding the port. Additionally try to connect using `sqlcmd` from the `cmd`.

Comment: wht you mean exactly with 'does not succesfully connected'? any error? iis itself will not connect to a db; any detail about the application?

Comment: It is problem related to the port number and I think I figured out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I left the reasons that I thought this as problem below - answer part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was port number problem at first, designating the initial(base) port number for the Database server, and the password policy should be turn off.

Password policy required me to change password regularly after some amount of time, and this was the error which is really hard to find